# Add validation list to cell (problem with localization)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm adding a validation list to a specific cell, so the user can select from a drop down list.

Every element is separated by `,`. This works fine. However if a German version of excel is used, sometimes `,` is the separator and sometimes it is `;`. I cannot figure out which one to use.

I want to add a validation list to a cell. I do this by adding a validation with the type xlValidateList and a formula like `"eggs,milk,apples"`.

The result is that the user can select from a dropdown menu that looks like this:

```
eggs
milk
apples
```

Yet sometimes in the German version of excel this list is only one element long and reads:

```
eggs,milk,apples
```

I already tried checking which language excel is set to and if it is German, replacing "," with ";". This works, but only sometimes. Some other times (after restarting excel) `,` is expected yet again.

My code for setting the list:

```vb
ws.Cells(16, column) = vbNullString
ws.Cells(16, column).Validation.Delete
ws.Cells(16, column).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=convertToLocale(portListAsString)
ws.Cells(16, column).Select
```

The convertToLocale function basically checks if `Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)` equals `1031` and replaces `,` with `;` accordingly. Sometimes the output is as expected, sometimes it is:
`eggs;milk;apples`

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using a list literal like `eggs,milk,apples` put the texts eggs, milk and apples in cells and use the cell range address as `Formula1` then. This is locale independent. The list data sheet my be hidden then. Example: `.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=hiddenSheet!$A$1:$A$3"`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
Sub Test()

Dim MyArray As Variant
MyArray = Array("eggs", "milk", "apples")

With ws.Cells(16, column).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyArray, ",")
End With

End Sub
```

My Dutch system uses the semicolon but never had any issues I had to replace the universal comma in VBA.

Comment: No, since it introduces the same problem with ```,``` as a separator.

Comment: Then I suggest to use either @Axelrichter his good idea, or implement this code in a `Workbook.Open` event. That way you will ensure (hopefully) the right delimiter is used no matter what the regional settings are.